# How to create AppImage for a Zsh script, including it?

Tags: package, zsh, appimage, appimage-builder

I would want to create AppImage for a script that has only one dependency – Zshell. I've found `appimagetool` but it doesn't give an easy answer of how to automatically bundle Zshell in the package.

I've tried `appimagetool n-commodore` (n-commodore is the directory with the script), however it didn't copy Zshell into the package. This is understandable, as the tool doesn't know anything about Zsh. However, I have now a problem of deciding of how should I include Zsh in the package. Should I compile it with a custom `--prefix …prefix…`, or if I should include also `libgdbm.so`, which is required as Zsh will be build with `zsh/db/gdbm` module?